# Unable to run spring struts maven project on WebLogic 10.3.3 using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, struts2, eclipse-plugin, weblogic

If I build this project to war and deploy it on WebLogic, it works well, but if I run on server using Eclipse, i got this error:

```
Caused By: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory 
with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - 
zip:D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/admini/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.3.12/struts2-core-2.3.12.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - 
zip:H:/runtime/weblogic1033/user_projects/domains/crmFrameworkDomain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/nefp93/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.12.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
```

stackTrace

```
<2013/4/20 下午06時59分34秒 CST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.
Unable to load configuration. - bean - zip:H:/runtime/weblogic1033/user_projects/domains/crmFrameworkDomain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/nefp93/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.12.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:332)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: Unable to load configuration. - bean - zip:H:/runtime/weblogic1033/user_projects/domains/crmFrameworkDomain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/nefp93/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.12.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:473)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - zip:H:/runtime/weblogic1033/user_projects/domains/crmFrameworkDomain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/nefp93/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.12.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:226)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - zip:D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/admini/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.3.12/struts2-core-2.3.12.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - zip:H:/runtime/weblogic1033/user_projects/domains/crmFrameworkDomain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/nefp93/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.12.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:229)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:226)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

> 

I don't know why there's another struts2-core.2.3.12.jar in _auto_generated_ear

Is there any configuration of plugins should i change?

weblogic 10.3.3
jdk 1.6
eclipse juno
maven 3.0.5

and here is my eclipse project archive:
[Loki.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16041054/Loki.zip)

Comment: What eclipse build number do you use?

Comment: Build id: 20130225-0426

Comment: what if you delete one of the jars from the lib, make sure only one jar is loaded.

Comment: jars in /WEB-INF/lib is maven dependency, i think the problem is _auto_generated_ear

Comment: I have the same problem: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2MRwpRk5. Eclipse Juno, JDK 1.6, maven 2.2.1, m2e and m2e-wtp.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.
In my case the one or more action classes configured in the struts.xml not defined on the package.
Once i defined the missing classes it worked fine.
please ensure all the action classes configured in struts.xml were defined in correct location.

struts.xml

```
 <action name="welcome" class="com.vk.translate.action.DummyAction">
            <result name="success">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

DummyAction is not defined in above code.
Once i defined it worked.